# JQuery advice or suggestion for new alternative solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a better way of doing this

```
$("#<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>").mouseleave(function () {
    var t_name = this.value;

    if (t_name == "") {
        $(this).val("Name");
        $("#<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>").addClass("grey_add");
        $("#<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>").removeClass("black_add");
    }
});
```

What this code does is when you scroll out of the textbox it leaves the it returns to you `"Name"`.

A con about using this technique is when user move mouse out the textbox it fills something in when user types.

Comment: Are you looking for a watermark / placeholder text solution?

Comment: perhaps you should use a 'focus lost' event (I forget the exact term in jquery)

Comment: an example of what i want is something similar to the search function on the top right of the screen of stackoverflow

Comment: The search box uses the `placeholder` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple with jQuery, check this:

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="Name" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#myInput').focusin(function() {
      $(this).val('');   
  });

  $('#myInput').focusout(function() {
      $(this).val('Name');   
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ccc');
  }); 
});
```

Here goes [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UEq8/).
No need for plugins or much code for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="search" placeholder="<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>"/>
```

no javascript needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>").blur(function () {
    var t_name = this.value;

    if (t_name == "") {
        $(this).val("Name");
        $("#<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>").addClass("grey_add");
        $("#<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>").removeClass("black_add");
    }
});
```

This event happens when you focus on something else, which is what the textbox at the top right of stack overflow probably uses.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the watermark plugin I was posting about here:

[Custom jQuery plugin return val()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891568/custom-jquery-plugin-return-val/11891646#11891646)

Just edit it to be `mouseover / mouseout` instead of on `focus/blur`.

[**jsFiddle edited to show mouseover/mouseout**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkas5/3/)